# How to generate a second okHttp instance after authentication and inject it using Dagger at runtime

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, runtime, dagger-2

I'm using dagger2 to inject several components into my application.
For this i created the following modules:

```
@Module
public class NetModule {

    private final Application mApp;

    public NetModule(Application app) {
        this.app = app;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Cache provideOkHttpCache() {
        int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
        return new Cache(app.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);
    }

    @Provides
    OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(Cache cache) {
        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cache(cache);
        client.connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        return client.build();
    }
}
```

I've already created a second module with another Okhttp (with the interceptor):

```
@Module
public class NetModuleInterceptor {

    private final Applcation app;
    private final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration;
    private final Interceptor interceptor;

    public NetModuleInterceptor(Application application, ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration) {
        this.app = application;
        this.clientConfiguration = clientConfiguration;
        if (clientConfiguration != null) {
            this.interceptor = new RetrofitRequestInterceptor(clientConfiguration);
        } else {
            this.interceptor = null;
        }
    }


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Cache provideOkHttpCache() {
        int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
        return new Cache(app.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(Cache cache) {

        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cache(cache);

        if (interceptor != null) {
            client.addInterceptor(interceptor);
        }
        client.connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        return client.build();
    }

    ClientConfiguration provideClientConfiguration() {
        return new ClientConfiguration(app, null, "");
    }
}
```

The NetModuleInterceptor can be instantiated only after receiving a token and a secret from the server and with those 2 key generating an interceptor. After instantiating the NetModuleInterceptor i would like to inject it into the first module (NetModule).

How can this be done using Dagger2 at runtime (using only one module).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe see this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37050348/1837367